# AndroidでNanoHTPD.javaを使って80番ポートでLISTENを行う

Tags: android, nanohttpd

Androidアプリケーションを作っていますが、NanoHTTPD.javaを使って80番ポートでLISTENを行いたいと思っています。

```
private static final int PORT = 80;
// (省略)
private class MyHTTPD extends NanoHTTPD {
    public MyHTTPD() throws IOException {
        super(PORT, null);
    }

    // サーバ要求の応答メッセージ
    @Override
    public Response serve(String uri, String method, Properties header,
            Properties parms, Properties files) {
       Inputstream is = null;
        // 色々と処理
       return new NanoHTTPD.Response(HTTP_OK, MIME_DEFAULT_BINARY, is);
    }
}
```

にて80番をLISTENしたいのですが、80番での配信ができません。
（起動していないような状況です）
またポート番号を8765にすると可能になります。

adb shellで80番ポートが他に使われていないか確認しましたが、

```
$ netstat -anp | grep 80
tcp       0      0 (本体のIP):56368      (削除):80       TIME_WAIT
tcp6      0      0 ::ffff:(本体のIP):42273 ::ffff:(削除):80 ESTABLISHED
tcp6      1      0 ::ffff:(本体のIP):51351 ::ffff:(削除):80 CLOSE_WAIT
```

と無い模様です。androidではwell knownポートは使えないのでしょうか？
対処方法も含めてご存知であればご教示お願いします。

Comment: 1024 番未満のポートは特権ポート(privileged ports）と言いまして、root 権限がないと listen できません。